# ActionPerformed jumps out of method

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, actionlistener

I have a ActionListener:

```
class ChangeLevelClickListener implements ActionListener{
    public ChangeLevelClickListener(){ }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        removeAllOldPanels();
        rebuildLevel(2);
    }
}
```

And when i debug the program the method removeAllOldPanels() gets called:

```
private void removeAllOldPanels(){ //<-here the program just jumps back to the actionperformed function and doesnt enter the loop
    for(JPanel panel : panels){
        getContentPane().remove(panel);
    }
}
```

BUT as marked in the code the program just doesn't enter the function and there is also no exception.
This ActionListener is a class inside the class where removeAllOldPanels() lies.

Comment: Could be your `panels` array is empty. Add `System.out.println()` statements and see which gets executed on the console.

Comment: Consider posting a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) to help reduce the guesswork.

Comment: @icza But the program doesn't even enter the method and i guarantee the panels array is full of content

Comment: @CuppleKay Then in this case you need to provide more info. Or put `System.out.println()` statements and post us what gets printed to the output.

Comment: @icza Do i have to set anything to public because the ActionListener class is inside the other class or is private ok?

Comment: @CuppleKay Private is ok, you don't need to make it public.

Comment: @icza It's too complicated to make an example. What do you think would cause a program to skip an entire method before even entering it

Comment: @CuppleKay If you can't form a SSCCE you won't likely get your problem solved here. If the situation is really that the method body is not executed (which I doubt), I would think of maybe the source code is not in sync with the compiled byte code. Clean/clear/recompile/restart. I also asked to place `System.out.println()` statements and post what you see which you haven't.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible since it's not a static void that you might need an instance of your class to call it?  I'm certainly not really good in java so sorry if I'm wrong.

so instead make it either

```
private static void removeAllOldPanels(){ //<-here the program just jumps back to the actionperformed function and doesnt enter the loop
for(JPanel panel : panels){
    getContentPane().remove(panel);
}
```

}

or

```
ChangeLevelClickListener myLevelClickListener = new ChangeLevelClickListener();
```

and then

```
myLevelClickListener.removeAllOldPanels();
```